# Yii framework possible language

Tags: php, yii, multilingual

When using EasyMultiLanguage extension (Yii framework) I got this code:

```
'params'=>array(
    'languages'=>array(
        'en' => 'English',
        'fr' => 'French',
        'ru' => 'Русский',
        'de' => 'Deutsche',

    ),
    'default_language' => 'en',
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
```

My question is how many languages which yii support, and what are they?

Comment: The above code is in config/main.php. When i tried to edit my form base on EasyMultiLanguage, I realize that when I set one of those languages, it becomes Yii current language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Yii supports as many languages as you want it to. If it's not included in the framework, you can translate it yourself. For the included languages you can look in the Yii directory under `framework/messages`. That's where all the message translations are stored.

For non-framework messages (strings that you add yourself) you'll have to specify the translations yourself via the `Yii::app()->messages`-component (this is a variant of a [`CMessageSource`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMessageSource)).